# regex input validation for mobile number 03025498448 using C#

Tags: regex

I am trying to do regex validation for 11 digit mobile number of type 03025398448.Where first 3 digits are constant 030 and remaining 8 digits are from 0 to 9 (any number) and 1st digit could be written in +92 format .So, help me for this number regex code

Comment: Show us the range of inputs along with your C# code.

Comment: first digit 0 or +92

Comment: Are you saying that the `+92` is _optional_, meaning a number may or may not start with `+92`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the number should start with 030 and +92 is optional and when using +92 you should omit the leading zero, you could use:

[`^(?:\+9230|030)?\d{8}$`](https://regex101.com/r/PaoWVC/1)

**Explanation**

```
^              # From the beginning of the string
(?:            # Non capturing group
    \+9230|030 # Match +9230 or 030
)?             # close capturing group and make it optional
\d{8}          # Match 8 digits
$              # The end of the string
```

In C# you could use this as `string pattern = @"^(?:\+9230|030)?\d{8}$";`

[C# code](https://regex101.com/r/PaoWVC/3/codegen?language=csharp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use this regular expression:

```
^((\+?92)30[0-9]{8}|030[0-9]{8})$
```

Explanation

```
BeginOfLine
CapturingGroup
GroupNumber:1
OR: match either of the followings
Sequence: match all of the followings in order
CapturingGroup
GroupNumber:2
Sequence: match all of the followings in order
Repeat
+
optional
9 2
3 0
Repeat
AnyCharIn[ 0 to 9]
8 times
Sequence: match all of the followings in order
0 3 0
Repeat
AnyCharIn[ 0 to 9]
8 times
EndOfLine
```

Comment: Some kind of explanation would be great